# Error while posting SOAP Request using ZEEP

Tags: python-3.x, soapui, zeep

My actual XML that needs to be passed to SOAP UI is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://un.cow.e-funds.com">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:caseInquiryElement>
         <ws:caseInquiryRequest>
            <ws:caseNumber>775038604</ws:caseNumber>
            <ws:clientId></ws:clientId>
            <ws:lastRecordType></ws:lastRecordType>
            <ws:lastClientId></ws:lastClientId>
            <ws:lastAuthorizationNumber></ws:lastAuthorizationNumber>
         </ws:caseInquiryRequest>
      </ws:caseInquiryElement>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://un.cow.e-funds.com">
```

Hence I have Create a dictionary with the relevant data for ZEEP to convert into necessary XML as below

```
request={
'soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://un.cow.e-funds.com"' :
{
  'soapenv:Body':
  {
   'ws:caseInquiryElement' :
   {
    'ws:caseInquiryRequest' :
              {
              'ws:caseNumber' : '775038061',
              'ws:clientId' : '',
              'ws:lastRecordType' : '',
              'ws:lastClientId' : '',
              'ws:lastAuthorizationNumber' : ''
              },
   },
  },
}
}
```

And below is overall code to post the request using Python 3.4 and ZEEP.

```
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
request={
'soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://un.cow.e-funds.com"' :
{
  'soapenv:Body':
  {
   'ws:caseInquiryElement' :
   {
    'ws:caseInquiryRequest' :
              {
              'ws:caseNumber' : '775038061',
              'ws:clientId' : '',
              'ws:lastRecordType' : '',
              'ws:lastClientId' : '',
              'ws:lastAuthorizationNumber' : ''
              },
   },
  },
}
}
session = Session()
session.verify = False
transport = Transport(session=session)
client = Client(
    'https://devdia.rudges.ri.gov:50207/ebt/service?wsdl',
    transport=transport)

response = client.service.clientInquiry(**request)
```

When executing the above set of code , it results in the following error and not sure how to bypass, Any help is welcome.

```
>>> response = client.service.clientInquiry(**request)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\sparavasthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\zeep\proxy.py", line 45, in __call__
    kwargs,
  File "C:\Users\sparavasthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 119, in send
    operation, args, kwargs, client=client, options=options
  File "C:\Users\sparavasthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 68, in _create
    serialized = operation_obj.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sparavasthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\definitions.py", line 215, in create
    return self.input.serialize(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sparavasthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\messages\soap.py", line 68, in serialize
    body_value = self.body(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sparavasthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 57, in __call__
    instance = self.type(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sparavasthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 49, in __call__
    return self._value_class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sparavasthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\valueobjects.py", line 95, in __init__
    items = _process_signature(self._xsd_type, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sparavasthu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\valueobjects.py", line 235, in _process_signature
    xsd_type.signature(standalone=False),
TypeError: {http://un.cow.efunds.com}clientInquiryElement() got an unexpected keyword argument 'soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://un.cow.efunds.com"'. Signature: `serviceHeader: {http://un.cow.efunds.com}ServiceHeader, clientInquiryRequest: {http://un.cow.efunds.com}ClientInquiryRequest`
```

Comment: can you post the output of `python -mzeep https://devdia.rudges.ri.gov:50207/ebt/service?wsdl` ? if xml is already defined in wsdl then you don't need to post the raw xml, `zeep` would take care of it itself.

Comment: @Tarique If I execute the above command, I am getting `requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='devdia.rudges.ri.gov:', port=50207): Max retries exceeded with url: /ebt/ebtservice?wsdl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))` as it is https. That is why in the code I have used` session.verify = False`

Comment: please try: `python -mzeep  --no-verify --no-strict https://devdia.rudges.ri.gov:50207/ebt/service?wsdl`